# Add "allow" rule for selinux (Android)

Tags: android, selinux

I've a code like this:

```
type hal_foo_default, domain;
hal_server_domain (hal_foo_default, hal_example)
```

I need to add a new rule:

```
allow hal_foo_default hal_foo_default:tcp_socket { create bind listen accept };
```

Because I've denied message:

```
avc: denied { accept } for pid=1033 comm="android.hardwar" lport=33455 scontext=u:r:hal_foo_default:s0 tcontext=u:r:hal_foo_default:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=1
```

But at the compilation stage I've an error because Android have a [neverallow rule](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/public/hal_neverallows.te). How do I add a new rule in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

You can add you domain to this file like this

```
neverallow {
   halserverdomain
   -hal_automotive_socket_exemption
   -hal_tetheroffload_server
   -hal_wifi_server
   -hal_wifi_hostapd_server
   -hal_wifi_supplicant_server
   -hal_telephony_server
   -hal_foo_default //YOUR DOMAIN
} domain:{ tcp_socket udp_socket rawip_socket } *;
```

It is not canonic, but works